# Perl: issuing Net::ping to check a remote windows machine (from linux) cannot see it up

Tags: linux, windows, perl, ping

I'm using a Perl script (on Linux machine) to check if a Windows 10 desktop (on the same network) is up or not:

```
use Net::Ping;

$p = Net::Ping("tcp");

print "Host is alive.\n" if $p->ping("host_name");

$p->close()
```

This script does not see that the Windows desktop is alive. However, when I use "ping " from the terminal, it can see the Windows desktop and receives the echo from it.

Digging further in the problem, I found that the "ping" command uses "icmp" protocol. Thus, when I used this protocol in the "Net::Ping", it could see the Windows desktop alive.
However, running it using "icmp" requires root privilege and I cannot afford that.

Can any one help me in resolving why the "Net::Ping" with "tcp" protocol does not see the windows desktop as alive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a simple socket script to check if host is alive

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need root to ping? But imagine the problem is you are specifying TCP instead of ICMP.

Try this:

```
use Net::Ping; 
$timeout=5; 
$p=Net::Ping->new("icmp", $timeout) or die bye; 
print "$host is alive \n" if $p->ping($host); 
$p->close;
```

Comment: "icmp" protocol requires root privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Net::Ping, I have used "system()" to use the "ping" linux command:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

my $cpu = "cpu_name_to_test";
my $rslt = system("ping -q -c 1 $cpu >/dev/null 2>&1");

if (! $rslt) {
    print "$cpu is up.\n";
} else {
    print "$cpu is down!\n";
}
```